# VRF fulfillRandomness guarantees

Tags: chainlink

Is it guaranteed that Chainlink will eventually callback the `fulfillRandomness(bytes32, uint256)` function? How do we detect if a failure happened and respond to it? I don’t want my application to get stuck if the nodes fail and don’t respond. (Apologies if this is a dumb question, but I’ve read the docs here [https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices] and don’t see anything on the topic).

Reference: https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/

Comment: Nodes in Chainlink Network keep track of all requests, make a queue, and will eventually come back with the response. Just make sure to choose a safe block confirmation time and do not re-request randomness even if you don't get the answer right away.

Comment: @Andrej how do you choose a safe block confirmation time?

Comment: @Dominic since block confirmation time vary between blockchains, my suggestion is to check this page https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-security-considerations/#choose-a-safe-block-confirmation-time-which-will-vary-between-blockchains

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/#subscriptions), in case of you don't have enough fund for your consumer requests, your requests remain pending for up to 24 hours before expire, and requests will process automatically after have sufficient LINK.

It doesn't explain what happens to the request after 24 hours, but my guess is the request expires and won't get another chance to process forever.